# Check if a dataset has been updated with new table BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I currently have a dataset (eg: Traffic) with Shard tables that get added every week with the name `'Traffic_timestamp'` where timestamp is the day it is created.

I would like to check if a particular `'Traffic_timestamp'` is present in the dataset. Looking for an automatic way of checking instead of manually checking the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example (for BigQuery Standard SQL) should give you an idea

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(table_id, CONCAT('Traffic_', r'\d{8}'))
AND SUBSTR(table_id, -8) = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE())
```

You can adjust to whatever specific logic of `new table` you have
For example if you would looking for table for previous day  - you would use

```
AND SUBSTR(table_id, -8) = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Comment: table_id is actually a full table name (without project.dataset part). for example  - Traffic_20180817

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks. I think I did a small mistake wrt explaining my data. Thank you very much!

Comment: no problem. as i mentioned  - this is just an example and you can easy adjust it to your particular case :o)